# Why should I use EXISTS() function in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, exists

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable t1
  WHERE t1.id = :id AND
        EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.post_id = :id)
```

And when I remove that `EXISTS()` function, still my code works:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable t1
  WHERE t1.id = :id AND
        (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.post_id = :id LIMIT 1)
```

So why should I write that? What's its advantage?

Comment: Exists returns on the first match. Subquery retrieves all matching records. Go read the manual.

Comment: @Pred Thanks for the tip. But I've edited my second query, So is there any different now?

Comment: ANSI SQL compliance is one reason.

Comment: Typing `EXISTS` hurts, but `LIMIT 1` does not? `EXISTS` is semantically correct. Your second query will fail on other DBMSs, and simply a bad practice. If you accidentally fail to use 1 and use a column name instead, and the matching record contains a NULL or 0, MySQL will cast it to FALSE and your query will provide a false result.

Comment: your second query like `SELECT * FROM mytable t1 WHERE t1.id = :id AND 1` and this is a correct query. because `1` evaluate to true

Comment: **`EXISTS`** is *not* a SQL function. It's a SQL keyword. (In MySQL in particular, `EXISTS` is a reserved word.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short:

- `EXISTS` returns when it finds the first result instead of fetching all matching records (so it is more efficient when there are multiple records matching the criteria)
- `EXISTS` is semantically correct.
- When there is a column name instead of `1` in the second query, and the column contains `NULL`, `FALSE`, `0`, etc, MySQL will implicitly convert it to `FALSE`, which leads to a false result.
- `EXISTS` is actually defined by the ANSI standard, while the second form is not. (The second query may fail in other DBMS)

As an extra side note, you are fine with `*` too when you are using `EXISTS`, since it checks if there is a matching record, not the value.

Answer (score 1):

I gonna show the use case of `EXISTS`. Here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/066db1/1

*Note that a book can be co-authored by multiple authors*

### The original result:

```
| author |          books |
|--------|----------------|
|    A 1 | Book 1, Book 2 |
|    A 2 |         Book 3 |
|    A 3 | Book 1, Book 4 |
```

### Filter using Book 1 with `WHERE` condition:

```
| author |  books |
|--------|--------|
|    A 1 | Book 1 |
|    A 3 | Book 1 |
```

### Filter using Book 1 with `EXISTS`:

```
|author  |          books |
|--------|----------------|
|    A 1 | Book 2, Book 1 |
|    A 3 | Book 1, Book 4 |
```

The query:

```
SELECT 
  a.name AS author,
  group_concat(b.content SEPARATOR ", ") AS books
FROM
  books b
INNER JOIN bookAuthors ba ON
  ba.bookID = b.id
INNER JOIN authors a ON
  a.id = ba. authorID
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      bookAuthors
    WHERE
      bookAuthors.authorID = a.id
      AND bookAuthors.bookID = 1
  )
GROUP BY
  a.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

> If a subquery returns any rows at all, EXISTS subquery is TRUE, and NOT EXISTS subquery is FALSE.

And when you use `... (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.post_id = :id LIMIT 1)` you either return `1` on success or `NULL` on no thing which consider as `True` or `False` respectively.

Working with `Exists` is more professional because:

> Traditionally, an EXISTS subquery starts with SELECT *, but it could begin with SELECT 5 or SELECT column1 or anything at all. MySQL ignores the SELECT list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference.

It takes the best way to return `True` or `False`.

reference from [MySQL Dev site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)